# How to implement a SeriesInterpolate effect for a new Flash charting library?

Tags: flash, effects, charts, animation, axiis

I'm working with a hot new open-source Flash data visualization library (http://www.axiis.org)  It doesn't (yet) have a series interpolation effect, like the Adobe Flash Charting library does.

Can anyone point me at anything that would help me understand how to do it?  I gather it involves applying a tween effect between the old-data sprite and the new-data sprite.

Since I've never done any data vis graphics work, I suspect that it may well be beyond me to implement -- but I'd rather not give up before at least looking into what's involved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time becoming more educated, this is what I have determined:

1. Axiis library depends on Degrafa.
2. Degrafa tutorials on transforms and animation exist.
3. This one uses the Tweener class for animation: http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/flex-degrafa-tic-tac-toe-tutorial-series-introduction
4. Study of the Degrafa tutorials, Tweener tutorials and Axiis Library code will provide a solution.